# Apache Spark 3.2.0 structured stream using kafka oauth

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, strimzi

Is it possible to use oauth with pyspark structured streaming with spark 3.2.0.  I was able to get the plaintext to work fine but I the sasl mechanism doesn't appear to register for the kafka data source.

Example:

```
os.environ[
    'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages io.strimzi:kafka-oauth-client:0.9.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.0,' \
                             'za.co.absa:abris_2.12:5.0.0,org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1,' \
                             'org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.2.0,org.example:scalakafka:1.0-SNAPSHOT ' \
                             '--repositories ' \
                             'https://packages.confluent.io/maven/ --repositories https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ ' \
                             '--jars file:/kafka-oauth-client-0.9.0.jar --driver-class-path /.m2/repository/io/strimzi/kafka-oauth-client/0.9.0/kafka-oauth-client-0.9.0.jar ' \
                             '--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077 pyspark-shell '


saslConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required oauth.refresh.token={} " \
                 "oauth.client.id=\"{}\" oauth.token.endpoint.uri=\"{}\"".format(
        "a","b","c")

    df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "{}") \
        .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", saslConfig) \
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "{}") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "{}") \
        .option('kafka.sasl.mechanism', 'OAUTHBEARER') \
        .option('group.id', 'testgrp') \
        .option("kafka.sasl.login.callback.handler.class",
                "io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler") \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .option("subscribe", "{}") \
        .load()

    return df
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/AuthenticateCallbackHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:732)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:490)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.java:640)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:613)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.consumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$2(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$withRetriesWithoutInterrupt$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:594)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.withRetriesWithoutInterrupt(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:593)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.$anonfun$partitionsAssignedToConsumer$1(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThreadRunner.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThreadRunner.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.partitionsAssignedToConsumer(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.fetchEarliestOffsets(KafkaOffsetReaderConsumer.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.$anonfun$getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets$1(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:231)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.getOrCreateInitialPartitionOffsets(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaMicroBatchStream.initialOffset(KafkaMicroBatchStream.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$5(MicroBatchExecution.scala:394)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:387)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$constructNextBatch$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:384)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withProgressLocked(MicroBatchExecution.scala:627)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.constructNextBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:380)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:210)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:303)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:209)
```

I have tried to add the jars but it is never found in the class path for some reason for the io.strimzi.kafka.oauth.client.JaasClientOauthLoginCallbackHandler.  I tried it scala and it was able to load the jar

Update:
The only solution I found is to implement a ReadStream data source from what I can tell.

Comment: Where did you add the jars? For strizmi adding the jars in`/opt/kafka/libs` works

Comment: @taraf I built a library locally for the structured stream and jar in the path.  It worked well for me at least.